# php $_POST select option value not working undefined index error

Tags: php, mysql, post

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to 
mysql');
$dbname = 'vendordb';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
<html>
<div class="row">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" 
        method="post">
        <?php   
            $result=mysql_query("select crtname from crtinfo");

            echo "<select id='criteria1' name='criteria1'" . ">";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<option value=".$row[0]. ">". $row[0]. "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";

            $crt1=$_POST['criteria1'];
            echo $crt1;  
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Unable to get dropdown value in $_POST

Error:

Notice: Undefined index: criteria1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\dropdowntest.php on line 25
cannot get value from $_POST

Comment: The error is shown because you echo the post variable before it has been submitted by the form. Use isset() to check if the variable has been set before outputting it.

Comment: Refrain from using `mysql_*` syntaxes, they are already [depecrated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

Comment: i think you have to learn some HTML first.  `echo "<select id=criteria1 name=criteria1" . ">";` can you please explain this line?

Comment: changed it now in the post .. but cannot echo data

Comment: Are you aware that a POST value will only be set after you actually submitted your form?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure if this will fix it, this is a sample on how to prevent "Undefined index" errors from appearing by using `isset()`

```
if(isset($_POST["critera"])
{
    $crt1=$_POST['criteria1'];
    echo $crt1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get the post value. Try this:

```html
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to 
mysql');
$dbname = 'vendordb';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
<html>
<div class="row">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" 
        method="post">
        <?php   
            $result=mysql_query("select crtname from crtinfo");

            echo "<select id=criteria1 name=criteria1" . ">";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<option value=".$row[0]. ">". $row[0]. "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            
        ?>
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  <?php
        if(isset($_POST['criteria1'])){
            echo $_POST['criteria1'];
        }
    ?>
?>
</div>
```